# So long, and thanks for all the fish

Tags: discussion

Today I'm sending an email to Stack Exchange resigning my moderator position.

That's less dramatic than it sounds as I've been essentially retired for the past year but I have been helping out occasionally. I've considered resigning several times since things really started going crazy but instead marked myself as inactive. I decided to wait on the basis that I might be stepping in to help out again - if and only if I saw signs of improvement from Stack Exchange.

Instead I see multiple longstanding and respected Community Managers leaving (some not through their own choice it seems) and a pathetic non-apology to Monica for the way she was treated. A non-apology that clearly had only been drafted by a lawyer under duress.

So thank you for nominating me as moderator pro-tem. Thank you for voting for me as moderator. Thank you for all you've done over the years. And thank you for helping make Worldbuilding the site it is. Unfortunately I cannot continue to support a company that treats its community, its volunteers, or its employees like this.

I'm not deleting all my SE accounts but I will be looking for alternatives in the future. Stack Exchange today is not the Stack Exchange that I started supporting and advocating for many years ago and so reluctantly I must move on.

Comment: Tim, thank you for all you've done for Worldbuilding over its entire lifespan!  You made a big difference.

Comment: I resigned recently, and the last sentence is something I completely agree on. Thank you for your help on the site!

Comment: It's been fun :)

Comment: I haven't been here much, and am also exploring alternatives, but I did want to say I enjoyed reading your posts and will miss the well-researched answers you and others posted (like your shield only combat answer which is still one of my favorites)

Comment: I have to say, the *Hitchiker's Guide to the Galaxy* reference is very fitting.

Answer (score 20):

Tim, after the first mod elections in 2016 - when I joined the mod team - you and Monica were the two old hands. You'd been pro-tem mods since the start, and though I'd moderated other sites, Worldbuilding presented plenty of new challenges for me, size and wackiness among them. I'm grateful for the guidance and experience you and Monica (and later a CVn) gave me.

Also, remember [your answer to How do I drug a population in the most efficient way?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/848/627) That was the post that first brought me to Worldbuilding, from the HNQ list. So thanks for even getting me here in the first place. :-)

Best wishes for the future, Tim.

Comment: And I'm very happy that you found us, you have been and continue to be an incredibly valuable member of many communities.

Answer (score 16):

All your hard work appreciated by ordinary members like myself.  What you are saying is very much how I feel myself about "new" SE so I get where you're coming from.  Good luck with things in the future.

Comment: Thanks, you too. :)

Answer (score 13):

Tim,

As your accidental namesake can I just say that it has been a pleasure working alongside you on the site all this time and I considered no shame at all to be the 'number two' Tim B on the site. You will be missed to be sure, but for me there is just a little extra sadness to the loss of your insights as it is a little like seeing a spiritual big brother leaving for greener pastures.

If you ever find a good 'alternative' SE be sure to let us all know. It would be good to have the old crew back together in a collegiate culture, coming up with great answers to crazy questions.

All the very best for your future, Sir.

Comment: You too, I felt like the name was in good hands :)

Answer (score 1):

Understandable, and thanks for your hard work as moderator!

I'll just offer the same bit of cheap advice I did to Monica: keep in mind, as you search for alternatives to SE, that Stack Exchange is ***NOT*** the company.  Stack Exchange, truly, is us here in the community. Folks who, in this case, share an interest in geopoesy.

I didn't join this forum because yay! I get to be part of some online Company!  No, I joined because this is a community of creative people who share with me a similar sort of creativity. I didn't know what Stack Exchange the Company was; and I still don't know. I didn't care what Stack Exchange the Company was; and you know what? I still don't give a fiddler's fart what the Company is, who the people are who run (or ruin) it. They can go on with their corporate foolishness and political agendas for all I care. They're not why I'm here.

As you look for alternatives, keep in mind [my response in this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/132660/worldbuilding-forum-or-other-conversational-place/132662#132662)!

Answer (score 0):

i wish you well in your endeavours, may you find the place you fit in best.
thank you for sharing with us.